# htacces to redirect without params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have :

```
somesite.com/default.asp?id=param1&id2=param2
```

and want to redirect to

```
newsite.com/home
```

without any parameter after the "?" in the URL.

any idea?

And thanks

---

solution:

found it :

RewriteRule ^default.asp(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/index.php/? [R=301,NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, that's easy:

```
RewriteRule ^/default.asp(.*)$ http://newsite.com/site/hello [R=301,L]
```

Comment: that redirects but still redirect the params too so i get http://newsite.com/site/hello?id2=world