# Redirect to URls without parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

thanks for helping newbies like me with your competent answers: I have a question regarding redirects from URls with parameters to new URls without parameters, probably using the .htaccess file. 
I have tried answers on questions like this
[htacces to redirect without params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589335/htacces-to-redirect-without-params)
[301 Redirect of old url with parameters to a path without parametes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277154/301-redirect-of-old-url-with-parameters-to-a-path-without-parametes)

but I'm still unsure how to proceed correctly.

So here is my problem: the old URL structure
http://www.mysite.com/my-files/query-qry?origen=1&destino=&aerolinea=DE&proveedor=barceloviajes&clase=F&escalas=

should redirect to this one: 
http://www.mysite.com/my-files/query-qry

to put it short: I want to add a 301 redirection without all parameters. What is the best and fastest solution and is there a rule that can be applied?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="" #if there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.* #wordpress users: allow post tempalinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.* #wordpress users: don't break admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

http://briancray.com/posts/htaccess-hack-remove-url-query-strings/

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and the link to this tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

> `To put it short: I want to add a 301 redirection without all parameters.`

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better than using a final ?, you should use the [qsdiscard](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/fr/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag `QSD`.
For your case :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^my-files/query-qry my-files/query-qry [QSD,L,R=301]
```